# Where can I find limber scales?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

I am having trouble finding Limber Scales for item crafting. I have a few of them, but I don't know where I got them from. Where can I find Limber Scales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 3 ways to get Limber Scales. In order of quickest to slowest:

- Harvesting Swarm-shockers on the 5th layer.
- Fishing for and catching Ikenosuke. Can be found on 2nd Layer (Terminal Pond, Edge of the Abyss, Corpse-Weaver Den) and 3rd Layer (Trapped Pirate Ship). ([Thanks to redacted for this info](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/400466/revisions))
- Kiyui can randomly give a Limber Scale as a reward when he asks for a shiny rock.

If you don't have access to the 5th layer, but you have a Moon Whistle or better, I recommend the following strategy to farm around 3-6 Limber Scales per trip:

- Head to The Abyss and choose the 3rd Layer (Requires a Moon Whistle)
- Turn around and travel to Edge of The Abyss (2nd Layer)
- Walk up the hill and travel to the Seeker Camp. (Stay near the sides to avoid a potential forced encounter)
- Head up the stairs, turn left, and travel to Edge of the Abyss
- Run towards the pond and catch all the Inosuke
- Head south and travel to Terminal Pond
- Catch all the Inosuke
- Eat food to restore your hunger until you can fast travel to the 1st layer and return to Orth

Answer (score 2):

You probably got them by catching Ikenosuke.

[image]

Mostly found on layer 2, so either Terminal Pond or Edge of the Abyss.

(note: that said, some quest have a low chance to give these as a reward.)